# Embedded database on external drive

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Have some application which uses SQL Server database on client server. Some time ago client requested to install application on external disk to be given someone else. My problem is somehow i have to attach database on external disk. Is it possible somehow to install sql server database on pendrive along with application? I heard something about sql compact. Can you update me on that topic?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used SQL Compact but SQL Compact is suitable for in-proc, small, light-weight databases but has certain limitations as compared to SQL Express, no support for views, stored procedures, remote data access etc. You can find more at [sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx)

In a recent project, one of my clients had similar requirements and this is how achieved it with SQL Server Express.

As per my configuration I placed both the application and the database on the external disk. The database was placed in a subfolder named *Database* in the *Bin* folder. I declared my connection string as

```
Data Source=SERVER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS_INSTANCE;AttachDbFilename=DATABASE_FILE_NAME_WITH_FULL_PATH;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

As a quick solution `SERVER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS_INSTANCE` was configured and taken from `App.Config` but `DATABASE_FILE_NAME_WITH_FULL_PATH` was generated dynamically (*external drive letters may change*) using path constructs such as `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "Database\ABC.MDF")` etc. and inserted into the DataConnection string. So, whenever the application runs it searches for the ABC.MDF in Database subfolder of application executable path. You may need to tweak this approach as per your requirements such as Application.StartupPath / Application.ExecutablePath etc.

For more information and another example on `AttachDbFilename` check MSDN [system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)